# Trouble with a php foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if an email already exists in our db.

```
var_dump($email);
output: array(2)
{
   [0]=> string(22) "xxxx7@gmail.com"
   [1]=> string(19) "yyyyy@gmail.com"
}
foreach($email as $em)
{
   $sql = "SELECT * 
   from sf_guard_user sf,personal pi
   where pi.user_id = sf.id
   and sf.email_address = '$em'";   
   $query = $db->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $alreadyexist[$count++] = $query->fetchAll();
}
```

These two emails exist in our db, but the result contains only one array.

What is the problem with my `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `store_result` and then `num_rows`:

```
 $query = $db->prepare($sql);
 $query->execute();
 $query->store_result();
 if($query->num_rows > 0){
     // exists
 }
 $query->close();
```

[Check out this link to learn more](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)